# jquery function to display arrows that point to buttons with a short explanation for each

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, user-interface

I am looking for  jquery / CSS functionality that will enable me to display to a user upon their first login arrows with explanations ... that point to specific locations-buttons.

I looked into various jquery tool tips but didn't find something similar to what I am looking for.

I would also like the background to be greyd out and the arrows to look more custom.

E.g something like this [picture](http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/TuneBash1.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: like the facebook or google+ when they apply a new design they provide explanation in balloons?

Comment: I am trying to remember how that is..but that's the idea..

Comment: i think you can make something from here. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this: http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/
You use data-step and data-intro tags and it highlights the things you want to highlight.